# Compare the column values and update another column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where we have first two entries for each test. Meaning for each test we have two entries, now I want to compare the test ranks and update the `LoginID` column in my table.

Sample data:

```
RANK | TestID | LoginID
-----+--------+---------
234     14       null   
235     14       null   
330     15       null   
331     15       null   
223     18       null   
222     18       null   
500     20       null
501     20       null
```

In the above table, I have two entries for each `testId`, now I need to compare the `RANK` column of the corresponding `TESTID` rows, and update the `LoginId` column with 1 and 2.

Finally I am looking for output like follows:

```
RANK | TestID | LoginID
-----+--------+---------
234     14       1  
235     14       2  
330     15       1  
331     15       2  
223     18       2  
222     18       1  
500     20       1
501     20       2
```

Can anyone suggest which is better way to achieve this? I tried with `min()` and `max()`, with `Case (When /then)` concept, but the query is not returning the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` with window function `row_number`:

```
merge into your_table t
using (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by testId order by rank) as rn
    from your_table t
) s on (
    t.rank = s.rank
    and t.testId = s.testId
    )
when matched then update set t.loginId = s.rn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try...

```
UPDATE tableName
SET LoginID = ( RANK MOD 2 ) + 1;
```

Note : This assumes that the lesser `LoginID` will always correspond with the lesser `RANK` for each `TestID`.

Further reading...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
 yourTable T,
 (
    SELECT
         TestID
        ,MIN( RANK) AS firstRank
        ,MAX( RANK) AS secondRank
    FROM
        yourTable
    GROUP BY
        TestID
) A
SET  RANK  = 
    CASE WHEN RANK = A.firstRank  THEN  1
         WHEN RANK = A.secondRank THEN  2
         END
```